# In electrophoresis, are positive and negative molecules obviously separated?

Tags: electrochemistry, biochemistry

I have just studied electrophoresis in biochemistry. The charged particles move to the oppsite charged electrodes whose speed is depended on their particle size. If that so, are negative and positive particles obviously separated into two distinct boundaries? As if we will find only negative particles near positive electrode and only positve particles near negative electrode.

Some searching I have done:

1. We cannot separate any two positive and negative ions because of their huge Coulombic force.
2. Exerted from electric field, a charged particle will move to the electrode and carry   counterion cloud together.

If (2) is true, why doesn't counterion move to its electrode but, instead, move along with charged particle?

If (1) is true, how is it possible that charged particles move to the electrode without separating from its counterion?

Comment: The process is similar to electrolytic cell. Did you think about how negatively charged ions go to positive electrode while positively charged ions go to negative electrode? Isn't it there possibility of ion separation? But it happens, How?